# How / Where to add Facebook Checkout pixel?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, order-success-page

I like to ask where I should place this code snippet:

```
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: 1,
    currency: 'SEK',
  });
```

I have added the normal facebook tracking code into the head for all pages. But I like to add this specific codesnippet to after the order is completed/success. And what variable name should I use for the value?

Which file, and what is the variable name? This is for Magento 2.3

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to either use a module or create one of your own for this:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/
- https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

If you choose to create a module, after you set up the base module. You can add `checkout_onepage_success.xml` file under `\CompanyName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order.success.additional.info">
            <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout\Success\Facebookpixel" name="modulename.checkout.success.facebookpixel" template="checkout/success/facebookpixel.phtml"
after="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then add `facebookpixel.phtml` under `\CompanyName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates\checkout`:

```
<?php
$order = $this->getOrder();
$pixelValue = number_format($order->getBaseGrandTotal(),2);
$pixelCurrency = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();

<script>
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
  value: <?php echo $pixelValue;?>,
  currency: '<?php echo $pixelCurrency;?>'
});
</script>
```

Then add success.php file under `\CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout\Success`:

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout\Success;

/**
 * FB Page Block
 */
class Facebookpixel extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory */
    protected $_salesFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $salesOrderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $salesOrderFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_salesFactory = $salesOrderFactory;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve current order
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\OrderFactory
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        $orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $this->_salesFactory->load($orderId);
    }
}
```